# Use and reset an int that is constantly incremented by another thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, atomic

I got a Task that counts the number of packets it receives from some source.

Every 250ms a timer fires up reads and outputs the count to the user. Right after i need to set the count back to 0.

My concern is that between reading and displaying the count, but BEFORE I set count=0, count has incremented in the other thread, so i end up losing counts by zeroing it out.

I am new to Threading so i have been at multiple options.

I looked into using Interlocked but as far as i know it only gives me arithmetic operations, i don't have the option to actually set the variable to value.

I was also looking into the ReaderWriterLockSlim, what i need is the most efficient / less overhead way to accomplish since there is lot of data coming across.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want Exchange:

```
int currentCount = System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref count, 0)
```

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.exchange?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Interlocked_Exchange_System_Int32__System_Int32_):

> Sets a 32-bit signed integer to a specified value and returns the original value, as an atomic operation.